# Sublime Text selected text and moving the caret to the beginning of a selection in html documents

Tags: sublimetext2

I have just begun using Sublime text after hearing good things about it.

I particularly like selecting between html tags using the zen coding plugin. However when I have a selected a large block of code using CONTROL+SHIFT+T  on mac OS X, I would appreciate being able to move to the beginning of the selection rather than scrolling all the way up with the mouse. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

Also I really like the balance braces feature in Mac Rabbits Espresso I know you can balance inwards using CTRL + SHIFT + B and was looking for a way of doing so in Sublime Text?

The keyboard shortcut to balance tags outwards is well documented as CTRL + SHiFT + N but I'd guess there is a way to do the opposite?

Comment: to get to the beginning of a selection, just the left arrow key is enough. One click and you're at the beginning of the selection. What's so hard in doing that?

Comment: Many thanks pretty obvious when you know how. left arrow key is perfect. I would still like to know the Mac Rabbits Espresso style inward balancing keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text however

Comment: when you need to know the shorcuts in Sublime Text, just check out settings. You can find the keyboard shortcuts in Preferences > Key bindings - Default. You can also assign new shortcuts. But use the Key bindings - User for adding custom shortcuts.

Comment: This gist link was quite good too with some good shortcuts, thanks for the help!
https://gist.github.com/1207002

Comment: I just did some more research and came up with this, I strongly suspect that Sublime Text 2 doesnt implement the balance inward tag, disappointing http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/wiki/Actions#Balance_Tag_Inward/Outward